# Mongoose middleware when adding multiple elements to a mongo array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Basically I have two mongodb collections, users and projects.
I want to keep track on which projects a user is working on, 
and also which users that are working on a given problem.

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  _projects: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Project'
  }]
})
```

and

```
const Project = mongoose.model('Project', new Schema({
    title: {
      type: String,
    },
    _usersWorkingOn: [{
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    }]
})
```

**Now, let's say i want to add multiple existing user-id to an existing project.
What would best practice be?**

Right now I'm using findOneAndUpdate to get the project document to push the user-id to the array. And then a mongoose middleware were I take the last added entry and get the user-id from there:

```
Schema.post('findOneAndUpdate', addProjectToUser)

function addProjectToUser(updatedProject, next) {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(
   updatedProject._usersWorkingOn[updatedProject._usersWorkingOn.length - 1],
    { $push: { '_projects': updatedProject._id}},
    { 'new': true }
  ).then(() => {
    next()
  })
}
```

This works when I add one user to a project. But if a want to add multiple users in one save, addProjectToUser have no way of knowing how many entries were added to the array.

Am I missing something here, or thinking about it all wrong?

Comment: Did you try pre hook of mongoose http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-pre

Comment: Now I am able to get the query, thank you. But I'm still unsure on how i target the user-id. The query has a field: _update:
 { '$push': { _ usersWorkingOn: '1a7de64844d565fcbasab89b' } }
Is there any way to extract the id?